# Finagle KetamaShardingServiceBuilder is unknown

Tags: load-balancing, finagle

We're using finagle as a rest api and as we need to have some exotic loadbalancing we used Finagle's `KetamaShardingServiceBuilder` available in 19.3

I tried updating finagle version to 20.10 but the `KetamaShardingServiceBuilder` seems gone. No indications in the changelog, and hardly any reference on the world wide web. It appears ShardingService (with KetamaShardingServiceBuilder) has completely been removed from `com.twitter.finagle.core.service` after version 20.3, without documentation or deprecation.

Hopefully any more insights here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jerry, it looks the question got answered in gitter, I will try to also close the loop here.

The ShardingService along with KetmaShardingServiceBuilder was [removed](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/commit/6943a8a0763b06bd61549af55d3b7e68d0773b31) in 20.3.0,
changelog [here](http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/changelog.html#id47), with the reason we believe it is a duplication of [PartioningService](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/develop/finagle-partitioning/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/partitioning/PartitioningService.scala), apologize not making it deprecated first to raise a warning.

Depends on which protocol you are using, more sophisticated partitioning APIs are provided as alternatives, more docs

http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Clients.html#partition-aware-client
http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/PartitionAwareClient.html

I believe the HashingPartitioningStrategy would provide an equivalent algorithm (if use the Ketama as the hasher) with KetamaShardingServiceBuilder as you are seeking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried linking here to the Gitter thread but I cannot get a URL which I can paste here. Your answer pretty much summarized the Gitter thread (https://gitter.im/twitter/finagle), which can be filtered on date (2021-03-22)